# Python pandas dependency with numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to install `pandas` in my project while `numpy==1.13.1` already part of project and i want to keep numpy==1.13.1 and install pandas so:

When I try to install with requirement.txt as:

```
numpy==1.13.1
pandas==0.20.0
```

it installs perfectly , but when try to `import pandas` in python interpreter, i get error:

```
ImportError: C extension: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

while if i only keep requirement.txt as:

```
pandas==0.20.0
```

it installs perfectly and `import pandas` works fine.

My assumption is that when numpy is already installed separately , it is not able to build with pandas while when there is no numpy installed it gets installed as pandas dependency and hence built fine, if this it true and i remove numpy from requirement.txt and allow it be installed as pandas dependency what version of pandas i should install so that at the end of all library installation from requirement.txt, i will have `numpy==1.13.1`.
If this is not the issue what should be way forward

My desired ouput is:

`numpy==1.13.1 installed 
pandas version any except 0.23.*
import pandas working fine`

`python version : 2.7.10`

Comment: Have you tried with a different version of `pandas`?

Comment: @norok2 i did, but could not find `pandas` with `numpy==1.13.1`

Comment: I just created a fresh environment and issued `pip install numpy==1.13.1`, then `pip install pandas` and `import pandas` just worked fine.

Comment: @norok2 is your python version 2.7.10 ?

Comment: @norok2 also did you install pandas==0.20.0 , cant use latest version of pandas as it as dependency of dateutil not matching with my requirement.

Comment: No, it was Python 3.7, perhaps you should then state all the restrictions you have right away...

Comment: anyway I tried with `numpy=1.13.1`, `pandas==0.20.0` within `python==2.7.10` (from Anaconda) and it all worked.

Comment: @norok2 thanks, probably there is some other issue, also i assume you tried `import pandas` in python interpreter